# DrRacket define begin set! probably should work but dont

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Im learning for exam of programming in lisp using DrRacket..

In presentation from lectures i found this code:

```
(define (f a b c)
    (define delta)
    (begin
        (set! delta (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)) 
        (if (>=? delta 0)
             (writeln ”są pierwiastki”)
             (writeln ”nie ma pierwiastków)))))
```

But it dont work.
DrRacket is showing:

```
. define: bad syntax (missing expression after identifier) in: (define delta)
```

Can't I set `delta` value later?

What is the problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: If the code is not in English, and you don't say what is the procedure supposed to do. It is hard to help. Even if it is in English, you should provide an expected result.

Comment: The function seems to be checking if a quadratic equation has real solutions, the text is in polish and reads something like "there are elements" and "no elements"

Comment: I read your comment, and also figured it out from the `delta`. But commented as a reference for future questions the OP can post. Maybe the future procedures will not be as straightforward as this one.

Answer (score 3):

The original error message is because

```
(define delta)
```

is missing a value. Instead it should be something like:

```
(define delta 0)
```

There some other issues:

- The double quotes weren't the `"` character and weren't recognized
  by Racket.
- Some parens were wrong.

Also I don't know why it was `define`-ing `delta`, then immediately
`set!`-ing it.

I tried to fix/simplify what you posted, and came up with the
following. But I'm not really sure what the function is supposed to
do, so I don't know if the example output is correct.

```
#lang racket
(define (f a b c)
  (define delta (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))
  (if (>= delta 0)
      (displayln "są pierwiastki")
      (displayln "nie ma pierwiastków")))

;; Example output:
(f 1 2 3)
;;-> nie ma pierwiastków
(f 1 200 3)
;;-> są pierwiastki
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#lang racket

(define (f a b c)
  (define delta 0)
  (set! delta (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))
  (if (>= delta 0)
      (displayln "są pierwiastki")
      (displayln "nie ma pierwiastków")))
```

What was wrong with your code:

- It's probably a copy-paste error, but in Scheme we delimit strings using the `"` character, not `”` as in your code. And the last line is missing the closing `"`.
- Although *some* interpreters accept a `define` without an initial value, the standard is that a value must be present after the variable name
- A closing parenthesis is missing at the end of the `set!` line
- The `define` and `set!` lines can be merged into a single line: `(define delta (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)))`
- The `>=?` operator is not standard in Scheme, it might work in your interpreter but if possible use the standard `>=`
- The `writeln` procedure is not standard in Scheme, in Racket you can substitute it for `displayln`
- Not really an error, but you don't need to write a `begin` inside a procedure definition, it's implicit

In conclusion: the code in the question seems to be intended for a different interpreter, this question was tagged `racket` but believe me, what you have is not valid Racket code - heck, is not even standard Scheme. Make sure to use the correct interpreter, and be very alert for typos in the text.

Answer (score 1):

I think Greg already has [a perfect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24175528/1565698) to your problem, but I just want to add the obvious `let` version of his code as well:

```scm
;; for a given ax^2+bx+c=0
;; this displays if it has at least one
;; real number answer or not
(define (equation-has-answer a b c)
  (let ((delta (- (* b b) (* 4 a c))))
    (if (>= delta 0)
        (displayln "Has answer(s)")
        (displayln "Has no answers"))))
```

To just make a predicate you can do this:

```scm
;; for a given ax^2+bx+c=0
;; this returns #t if it has at least one
;; real number answer and #f otherwise
(define (equation-has-answer? a b c)
  (>= (- (* b b) (* 4 a c)) 0))
```